# Possible overwriting to database table

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, database-connection

Let's say you have a database table name table1 with columns name and surname. Two different clients open the same view from the java application and get the data for same person at the same time.

1) First client changed the name and pressed save button to update database record.
2) Client2 still sees the old record on the screen and then pressed to save button to change the surname.

It actually overwrite the record by old name. I think to check and get the latest data before updating the database when I click button but I do not like this solution because of making a second query before update.

So how can we solve this problem by using Hibernate and without using Hibarnete. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Of course if you do not want that something will be overridden, then you have to check the data before an update. But it will be not always a real query with a good caching strategy. You could also use a timestamp with last update to compare it easier. Another strategy would be to lock the entities when the first user will read them. But that is normally not a good design for web applications or you have to integrate a messaging service, which will all user inform for an update who actually have open that entity. But I think that is not so easy to implement and a more advanced feature.

In short, compare the timestamp of an entity and if already updated, then compare the changes and show them for the user who wanted update that entity.

Comment: I forgot maybe you have also to be aware for concurrent updates with Hibernate [transaction_manager](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/transaction/TransactionFactory.html) or if someone uses JTA and minimum JPA 2.0 the [Transactional API](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/transaction/TransactionFactory.html)